# Exact hour of Windows 10 free upgrade period end

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

Everywhere I look I see "the free update period ends on July 29th". Well, okay. Would that be on `July 29th, 00:00:00 GMT+0`, `July 29th, 23:59:59 GMT+0` or some other obscure time? Even [Microsoft's FAQ page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12435/windows-10-upgrade-faq) only states the date, not the hour.

What is the exact time (within one hour error margin) of the free Windows 10 upgrade period end?

P.S.: Due to unforeseen circumstances, I need to know the exact time, so I can plan a trip to upgrade a machine at a remote location (read: one of my non-tech savvy relatives is terribly indecisive).

Comment: Do it on the 28th.

What are you going to do if the servers happened to go down prior to the 29th and they don't bother fixing them?

Comment: *shrug* Unless you're paid an *ungodly* amount of money, this isn't worth the pain. If they don't want an upgrade, leave it be. If they want the upgrade, you can always backup, and upgrade, then roll back. Leaving it to the *exact* hour is... kinda silly especially since you never know if your update will work out, or will be a pain.

Comment: @Geek, true, but you know...it is family. It would be nice to at least know if this thing ends at the start of 29th or the end of the day.

Comment: Ask Microsoft, they are the only people who can answer this off-topic question

Comment: @predi i really dont see how that matters...?

Comment: @djsmiley2k, you don't see how what matters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, "never leave it till the last minute" is good advice and they may be fair comments, but I can imagine scenarios where this might be useful to know. I think we can do better as a stack exchange community!

As such, If you go to the microsoft site:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-10-upgrade

From an old windows device (I just changed my user agent string to: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36`, you'll see:

[image]

I ran that just now, suggesting the actual deadline is **11am BST (GMT+1) on the 30th July**. Assuming their website is correct.